# Angular: md-datepicker input displaying as $invalid (red line)

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am retrieving json via a promise and binding to my model using this function.

```
var applyDataToScope = function(data){
    console.log(new Date(data.startDate));
    $scope.startDate = new Date(data.startDate);
};
```

However the md-datepicker displays as $invalid even though the date is correctly formatted within the md-datepicker input 'DD-MM-YYYY'.

```
<md-datepicker onkeydown="return false" required ng-model="startDate" class="date-input" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

The console outputs (as expected) with no errors:

```
Tue Jun 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

If I pick the same date using the picker the invalid styling disappears

I am formatting the date with the following config in my app

```
myApp.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
       return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
   };
});
```

Comment: If you log the date to the console is it a date object or a string?

Comment: I am parsing as a new Date object to the console. The JSON startDate is "Jun 13, 2017" so I think it's being successfully parsed